# MySQL trigger update a single row after delete

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am pretty new to this whole trigger thing in phpMyAdmin. So my idea was to create a trigger which updates a date_time in a single row after a delete.

```
BEGIN

UPDATE `test1` 

SET test1.updated_at = current_date()

WHERE (test1).id = test2.id;

END
```

UPDATED

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_row`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `update_row` AFTER DELETE ON `tabel1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE
`table2` SET table2.updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id = table2.id; END
```

Comment: That's quite a way from being correct syntax. Have a look at the manual examples here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: why not simply send 2 queries programmatically?

Comment: I have edited my question. He updates after delete but he updates every row not the single row

Comment: Can you please post the delete query too.

Comment: @calm its now updated

Comment: Do both tables have the same structure? 
I mean, does table2.id refers to table1.id.. if so there is a design problem.

Comment: I think its the set that makes the trouble cause he set the whole updated_at timestamp and maybe just sorts with the id

Comment: I think you will need to post tables structure as well.

Comment: i fixed the problem with limt at the end